# Can $ a_1\sin(b1*t + c1) \cdot a_2\sin(b_2t + c_2) = T $ be rewritten in terms of $t$?

Tags: trigonometry

**The short version:**

Can:

$$a_1 \sin(b_1 t + c_1) \cdot  a_2\cdot \sin(b_2 t + c_2) = T $$

be rewritten in terms of $t$, given $a$,$b$,$c$ and $T$ are constants?

**Some background (not needed to answer question):**

I'm writing an program which generates midi notes by looking at when a oscillator crosses a certain threshold. The easy (to program) method is to calculate the oscillator value at every sample, but I'd like to avoid doing 44100 calculations per second. The computationally least expensive method is just calculating when it should cross, and popping out a note then. Unfortunately, having only one oscillator is pretty boring, so the plan is to multiply two together, and have controllable phase/amplitude and frequency.

This feels like something I should be able to do, but after more scribbling than I'm proud of, I'm not much closer to the answer.

Edit: For brevity, if the answer is "yes, using only simple trigonometric identities", I will accept a simple "yes" as an answer.

Comment: Would sin(u)sin(v)=(1/2)(cos(u-v)-cos(u+v)) help?

Comment: That's the road I followed, but that comes down to something like k1*cos(gt) - k2*sin(gt) - k3 * cos(ht) + k4*sin(ht) = T/a1a2

The only road forwards there for me identity wise is turning everything back into sines, which is where I was coming from. 

At the moment it looks like the best option would be some sine approximation formula.

Comment: @teatime do you want the equation to be in the form $t = \text {something}$ ?

Comment: @A--B: Yes, excuse my incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 0):

It is already written in terms of $t$.  $T$ should not be a constant, it is the output of the sum of your two oscillators.  You can use the [function sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis) to write the sum of two sine waves as the product of two sine waves, 
$$\sin a + \sin b =2\sin \left( \frac {a+b}2 \right)\cos \left( \frac {a-b}2 \right)$$.  It is then easy to read off the zeros of the sum.  I don't understand what you mean by "pop out a note" when you cross zero.

Comment: What you see there is not a function that has to be computed for all t's. T _is_ a constant, it is a horizontal line, and I am interested in all points where crossings occur. 

From the programs point of view you can look at what the current time is and calculate the values, but if the crossing happens to be a small amount of time after a rhythmic beat, you have to wait until the next beat to send it (you cant sent a note into the past). I rather want all crossings, and dispatch the notes to their closest beat. That way I only recalculate when program changes occur.